# É possivel deixar connectionString de forma dinâmica?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, banco-de-dados, entity-framework, postgresql

Eu já li algo e sei que é possível deixar uma *connectionString* de forma dinâmica em uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC. Porem é possível criar *n* conexões onde cada usuário autenticado no sistema tem sua própria conexão com um determinado banco de dados?

**Sabe se que os banco são idênticos, apenas muda-se o local de cada um.**

Se alguém souber outra forma de resolver essa situação sugestões serão bem vindas, pois ao meu nível de conhecimento, uma aplicação web só tem apenas uma conexão, onde n usuários fazem as consultas, gravações, etc... e se mudar essa conexão muda para todos os usuários que estão acessando a mesma.

**#EDIT - 12/08 15:18**

Consegui algum avanço. Como uso o Entity, segue o que consegui obter:

```
public class Entidades : DbContext
    {

        public static string teste()
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session ["conString"] != null ? (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["conString"] : "Conexao";
        } 

        public Entidades() : base(teste()) {}

        public DbSet<Usuario> Usuario { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Clientes> Clientes { get; set; }...
}
```

Essa Session é criada no momento após o login do usuário, onde na coluna da tabela de usuários do banco de dados principal fica o nome da connectionString, armazeno o nome na sessão e uso a mesma.

Porém surge outra duvida, como faço para que de acordo com a inserção ou uma atualização de novos usuários e suas connectionString, é inserida de forma automatica no web.config as Connections? Existe essa possibilidade?

Comment: É possível sim, basta criar várias conections no web.config ou gerar elas concatenando strings.

Comment: Na opção de gerar a string, como eu faria pra declarar o provider? Sendo que hoje uso o Entity para fazer a conexão

Comment: Ao criar um Entidades seu você chama o construtor acima passando a string `: base("stringdeconexao")`. Acredito que seja isso que você quer.

Comment: Já tentei isso, mas quando coloco a string(Server=localhost;Database=DATABASE;User Id=postgres;Password=123456;) e não o nome da mesma qe esta no web.config, o Entity gera uma exceção algo como: "Invalid keyword server", porque ele nao reconhece o Provider="Npgsql".

Comment: Estranho, o nome da variável do construtor é `nameOrConnectionString`. Já tentou pegar uma string de conexão que funciona no web.config e jogar exatamente como ela é no construtor? As vezes a string está errada.

Comment: Sim sim, já testei dessa forma, achei estranho também... Mas acredito que se omitir o provider, ele busca o do SqlServer, que ao contrário do Npgsql não se usa o Server e sim DataSource...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que eu faria, no seu lugar, é mapear um contexto de informações do usuário em separado. Ele guarda não apenas os dados de conexão ao banco de dados do usuário, mas também informações adicionais sobre o login e suas permissões.

```
public UsuariosContext = new UsuariosContext();
```

Tendo isso, pode-se implementar [esta excelente *Extension* de troca de conexão de forma dinâmica](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20254520/1314276), a qual traduzo abaixo com algumas liberdades poéticas:

```
public static class DbContextExtensions
{
    // todos os parâmetros são opcionais.
    public static void MudarDatabase(
        this DbContext source,
        string initialCatalog = "",
        string dataSource = "",
        string userId = "",
        string password = "",
        bool integratedSecuity = true,
        string configConnectionStringName = "") 
        /* Este último parâmetro é usado quando o nome da connectionString
           usado pelo contexto é diferente do padrão, definido no início da 
           aplicação. */
    {
        try
        {

            var configNameEf = string.IsNullOrEmpty(configConnectionStringName)
                ? "DefaultConnection" 
                : configConnectionStringName;

            var entityConnectionStringBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder
                (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
                    .ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);

            var sqlConnectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
                (entityConnectionStringBuilder .ProviderConnectionString);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(initialCatalog))
                sqlConnectionStringBuilder.InitialCatalog = initialCatalog;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataSource))
                sqlConnectionStringBuilder.DataSource = dataSource;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
                sqlConnectionStringBuilder.UserID = userId;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
                sqlConnectionStringBuilder.Password = password;

            sqlConnectionStringBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = integratedSecuity;

            // Ponto de mudança da conexão
            source.Database.Connection.ConnectionString 
                = sqlConnectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Defina aqui seu tratamento de exceção.
        }
    }
}
```

Uso:

```
var db = new AplicacaoContexto();
// Defina abaixo apenas os parâmetros que irão mudar.
db.MudarDatabase(
    initialCatalog: "MeuUsuarioDatabase",
    userId: "usuario",
    password: "senha",
    dataSource: @".\sqlexpress"
);
```

Comment: Um tempo depois, eis que volto rs Tinha deixado de lado essa solução e apelei pra uma onde coloco manualmente no Web.config a string de conexão, porem não vem sendo muito eficaz. Caso eu tenho uma conexão/db padrão, onde o sistema vai buscar os dados do usuário e só apos a autenticação, muda-se o banco, em qual momento eu faço o uso do MudarDatabase? Após a autenticação do user?

Comment: Exatamente. O ideal é manter um contexto padrão, onde as informações do usuário possam ser facilmente buscadas.

Comment: Porem, mesmo passando por esse método e sem gerar nenhuma exception, a conexão ainda permanece a padrão. Pelo que reparei, a cada instância que a entidade principal é chamada, a connectionString é a padrão e não a modificada. Nao tem uma maneira de tornar isso um método estático? public EntidadesDB(string str = "Conexao") : base(str)
        {         
        }

Comment: Só criando um contexto para cada conexão, o que não vejo lógica para o seu caso.

Comment: Mas então, como que mudo de forma dinamica e "definitiva" a conexao com o banco? Ou a cada vez que for chamar a Entidade vou ter que chamar o MudarBanco ?

Comment: A cada vez que for chamar a Entidade vai ter que chamar o MudarBanco.

Comment: Sério que era simples assim? http://i.imgur.com/dJuzHgs.jpg

Comment: Sim, por que deveria ser complexo?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/162733/contextos-exclusivos-de-usu%C3%A1rios-autenticados da uma olhada @Cigano