# Contextos exclusivos de usuários autenticados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Usando o método recomendado pelo @Cigano nessa resposta ([É possivel deixar connectionString de forma dinâmica?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/146885/%C3%89-possivel-deixar-connectionstring-de-forma-din%C3%A2mica/149343)), consegui obter uma conexão dinâmica, e usando a ideia de se mapear um contexto com os dados do usuário como nome do banco, host, etc... me deparei com outro problema: **A cada usuário logado, os dados contidos no contexto são sobrescrito pelos dados do mais recente usuário autenticado.**

Qual a forma elegante de se criar um contexto para cada usuário logado no sistema onde um não ha interferência do outro?

Cookies? Sessions?

**Update**

A mudança do banco é feita a todo momento em que a entidade é chamada:

```
public EntidadesDCSystem(string str = "Conexao") : base(str)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var user = HttpContext.Current.Session["usrProfile"] as UsuarioContexto;
            this.MudarBanco(database: user.database, configConnectionStringName: "Conexao");
        }
    }
```

Fiz assim (com session), pois foi o único jeito que encontrei de dados de usuários não se misturarem. Segue onde monto essa session, que é no momento de login do user.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(AuthLogin form, string returnUrl)
    {
        ...

        //FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(usr.nome, true);
        var userData = usr.descricao + '|' + usr.usuarioid;

        var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
            usr.nome,
            DateTime.Now,
            DateTime.Now.AddHours(8),
            true,
            userData);

        var encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

        var userProfile = new UsuarioContexto
        {
            nome = usr.nome,
            userid = usr.usuarioid,
            database = usr.conexao
        };

        Session["usrProfile"] = userProfile;

        ...
    }
```

Comment: Depende. Como você tá fazendo a autenticação da aplicação? Não sei como funciona na maioria dos casos, mas usando o ASP.NET Identity, isso não deveria acontecer não...

Comment: Uso ainda o FormsAuthentication rs

Comment: Ok, e em qual momento você está fazendo a troca da database? Tem como postar este código? (Não o que faz a troca, mas o que chama ele)

Comment: Como mencionei na edição, a troca ocorre toda vez que a entidade é chamada, através de dados passado pela session criada no login. @jbueno

Comment: Você já deu uma olhada em `Claims`?

Comment: @JcSaint Entao, no projeto qe estou trabalhando esta com formsAuthentication, Claims nao é pro Identity?

Answer (score 0):

> Qual a forma elegante de se criar um contexto para cada usuário logado no sistema onde um não ha interferência do outro?
>
> Cookies? Sessions?

Cookies seria a melhor alternativa. Os dados que caracterizam cada usuário ficam em suas máquinas e o sistema identifica qual a conexão correta por requisição.

Sobre sua implementação, `Session` tem problemas com balanceamento de carga. Uma sugestão usando Cookies seria:

```
var meuCookie = new HttpCookie("MeuCookie");

meuCookie.Values["Usuário"] = // Coloque o nome ou Id do Usuário aqui como String.
meuCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60);
Response.Cookies.Add(meuCookie);
```

Lendo:

```
var meuCookie = new HttpCookie("MeuCookie");
meuCookie = Request.Cookies["MeuCookie"];

if (meuCookie == null) 
    throw new Exception("Informação do usuário não encontrada.");

var usuario = meuCookie.Values["Usuário"];
```