# Connection string para diferentes usuários logados

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-4

Estou fazendo um um trabalho e me surgiu uma possibilidade que eu gostaria de saber se é possível realizar: o propósito dessa ideia é alternar uma determinada `connection string` conforme o usuário logado. Ou seja, eu terei uma `connection string` geral, que vai conter as informações do usuário para que ele realize o login, e no banco de dados dessa `connection string` eu terei as informações de outro banco de dados que esse usuário deve se conectar. Ou seja, cada grupo de usuários vai ter um banco de dados diferente para se conectar e a partir das informações do banco de dados que o usuário deve se conectar, eu montaria a `connection string` para ele.

É possível implementar algo assim ou existe uma solução melhor?

Comment: Já respondi isso antes. Veja se te atende: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/146885/%C3%89-possivel-deixar-connectionstring-de-forma-din%C3%A2mica/149343#149343

Answer (score 2, accepted):

você pode usar a abordagem de connection string dinâmica, alterando os dados de uma connection string genérica para os dados do banco que o usuário deverá utilizar, o armazenamento dos dados da conexão pode ficar no banco inicial de login.

O link abaixo tem um exemplo interessante de como utilizar esse recurso.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/bd6c67/dynamic-connecting-string-of-mssql-database-in-C-Sharp/

Espero ter ajudado.